# Java objects with serial number

Tags: java, object

I need to program a parent class (Plate) and some child classes (WoodenPlate, PorcelainPlate, etc) each of the Child Objects should have a serial number starting with 1, then 2, etc. 
Where should I store this information? Can I just increment a counter in the Parent Object?

Comment: You need to have a static counter in Child Class.

Comment: Which information? The "current" serial number?

Comment: Yeah, the current serial number. If I put the counter in the child class it wont increment in all instances, or will it? So eg
new WoodPlate would have serial Number 1
but, new PorcelainPlate would also have serial number 1 instead of 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your one of your `Child` class should look like:

```
class WoodenPlate extends Plate {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private int serialNumber;

    public WoodenPlate() {
        serialNumber = ++counter;
    }
}
```

And then for each instance of `WoodenPlate`, you can access the `serialNumber` using *public accessors*

You can define rest of your `Child` classes like this. With each one of them having a `static` counter and a `serialNumber` field.

---

If you don't want the count to start from `1` fro every `Child`, but just want the count to continue from the previous one regardless of which Child class was instantiated, then you should have those fields in `Parent` class:

```
class Parent {
    protected static int counter = 0;
    protected int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

And then remove the field from each of your `Child` class.

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly for numbering the objects of one child class, but what I need would be too number across all child classes. :/ 
So when I call new childA(); it should have count 1 and with new childB(); it should have count 2

Comment: @Ragnr. I thought you want for every Child, the count should start with `1`. If you want your `count` to continue like `1, 2, 3` regardless of which Child class is instantiated, then you need to have those fields in your `Parent` class.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, your help is much appreciated. Thanks for your time